# Ajax keeps site on the Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, readystate

I ve been trying to figure out how to make this work.

```
var request;

if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
    request= new XMLHttpRequest();  
}else{
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}


var handleStateChange = function () {
   switch (request.readyState) {
      case 0 : // UNINITIALIZED
      case 1 : // LOADING
      case 2 : // LOADED
      case 3 : // INTERACTIVE
      break;
      case 4 : // COMPLETED
      break;
      default: alert("error");
   }
}


/*request.onreadystatechange=handleStateChange;*/
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if((request.status === 200) && (request.readyState === 4)){
        console.log(request);
        document.writeln(request.responseText); 
    }

}
request.open('GET','data.txt');
request.send();
```

I found similar problems here in stackoverflow, but yet I havent figured out why its behaving this way (Im new to Ajax).

So the problem is, when I have `request.open('GET','data.txt');` its causing the page to stay on loading mode and the console.log doesnt show anything.

I google around and found in stackoverflow this solution `request.onreadystatechange=handleStateChange;`

which seems to be fixing the problem.  unfortunately it overrides the `request.onreadystatechange = function(){}`. Console works and the data.txt  content wont show on the web.

If I comment it out, the content shows on the web, but the page keeps loading again.

I figured that its something to do with readyState and that by the time it reaches 4 the responseText is empty. But how can I get it to show the content and the console.log?

Thank you in advance for your time :)

Comment: @FrebinFrancis really why that is good and this xmlhttprequest is bad? any reasons other that syntactical sugar.

Comment: @Metalbreath why do you need this: `handleStateChange` at all.

Comment: see you will get much control over the XML http requests when using Ajax helpers, because they already done it for you.

Comment: @Metalbreath you have commented out the outer one but another is inside too: `request.onreadystatechange=handleStateChange;`.

Comment: @FrebinFrancis As I mentioned, Im new to Ajax. I just started learning the basics. I had no idea about ajax helpers but thank you for mentioning it. I will take a look at them. seems to be helpful :)

Comment: @Jai basically is the function I used for 'request.onreadystatechange=handleStateChange'. without it the website is on constant load and wont show any console results. but with it console works without showing any results on the website. 
I ve seen the extra bit of code after I made this post and I forgot to edit it. thank you for the notice (Edited)

Comment: @Metalbreath just posted an answer, may be you are using a wrong js method `writeln`.

Answer (score 0):

*but with it console works without showing any results on the website*

As per your comment, I can suggest you that you are using a wrong method. There is no `writeln` method in javascript, instead you are suggested to use `.write()`*(although not recommended)*.

change to this:

```
document.write(request.responseText);
```

or better:

```
document.body.innerHTML = request.responseText; // use this response contains html tags
```

or:

```
document.body.textContent = request.responseText; // use this response is just text
```

Comment: thats a nice information. Thank you.
I havent even noticed. 

It seemed that my problem was caused by firebug. many get this problem.
It works now. I hope it will stay this way :)